# CMAKE COMPILER_CXX_ID behaviour

Tags: c++, cmake

Does

```
$<COMPILER_CXX_ID:Clang>
```

will return `1` for `Clang` and `AppleClang`

According to the doc I would say yes but I'm not sure...

> `1` if the CMake-id of the CXX compiler **matches** comp, otherwise `0`

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html

Comment: Have you *tried* it? Even if a test isn't fully conclusive it might at least give a hint about the answer.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have an AppleClang right there. But need to support it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: When using `$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>` and having `CMP0025` to `NEW` then `AppleClang` won't match it.

## Matching both

First I suppose the policy [CMP0025](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0025.html) is set to `NEW` to get `AppleClang` on MacOS with `clang` provided by `Xcode`

```
if (POLICY CMP0025)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0025 NEW)
endif()
```

To match both compilers with `CMP0025` set to `NEW` you have two options

### Option 1

first create a variable:

```
if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "Clang")
  set(USING_CLANG ON)
else()
  set(USING_CLANG OFF)
endif()
```

note: notice the use of `MATCHES` instead of `EQUALS`

Then you can use it in your generator expression:

```
target_compile_definition(target PUBLIC
  $<$<BOOL:${USING_CLANG}>:-DUSE_CLANG>)
```

### Option 2

You may also use:

```
target_compile_definition(target PUBLIC
$<$<OR:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:AppleClang>>:-DUSE_CLANG>
```

## Annexe

You can find a working example at https://github.com/Mizux/cmp0025

note: Don't hesitate to look at the Travis-CI log (by clicking on the build badge)